# F# Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {

Tags: parsing, f#, json.net

I have a log that need to serialize/deserialize with JSON.net 11.0.2. I can serialize it ok, but when deserialize it fail:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered
>   while parsing value: {. Path '[0].data', line 10, position 13.

The object is

```
type LogRow = {
    log_id:int64
    source_id:int32
    source:string
    action:string
    data:string
    changeby:string
    version:int32
    timestamp:DateTime
}
```

and the JSON is:

```
[
  {
    "log_id": -1,
    "source": "Auth",
    "source_id": -1,
    "action": "CreatedUser",
    "version": -2,
    "changeby": "admin",
    "timeStamp": "2018-06-14T20:33:52.835199Z",
    "data": {
  "user_id": -1,
  "username": "admin",
  "name": "Administrator",
  "email": "test@test.com",
  "password": "123",
  "role": "admin",
  "is_active": true
}
  }
]
```

I try to deserialize with the object and as a dictionary like:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<string, string>>>(json)
```

In both cases it fail. I try the same json in python and is working, so must be something with json.net?

P.D: The content of DATA is not fixed. That is why I need to get it as string, not as a object.

Answer (score 1):

For data to be a string type, they data needs to be in quotes.
If it's not in quotes, it assumes it's another object and will try and deserialize that

Comment: Ok, but then how force it to be string in this case?

Comment: Add double quotes around the data

Comment: Or get data as dynamic?

Comment: put double quotes mess with the rest of the data. Is possible to override how "Data" is deserialized? so I can take all as string?

Comment: Depending on what you want to do with data, you could make the type to serialise into "dynamic"

Comment: *Is possible to override how "Data" is deserialized? so I can take all as string?* - what do you want as the contents of that string -- the raw JSON?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
List<Dictionary<string, object>>
```

for the target serialization type -- Some of the values in your JSON object are not string values.

Also, have you tried using

```
List<LogRow>
```

as the serialization type? That would be ideal, since that's what you started with, assuming I'm not misunderstanding something.